# Browser Login form auto-complete solution

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to implement a browser auto-complete feature for my application Login view. However it seems that the only [solution is through FormPanel](http://jamies-gwt.blogspot.com/2011/08/gwt-and-usernamepassword-autocomplete.html). The problem with this is that it is intended to be used with standard servlet; in this case I will need to rewrite my "login" code, since what I have is Login RPC. Is there a way to do browser login form auto-complete with using GWT RPC for the Login service?

EDIT:

I tried this code:

```
    FormPanel form = FormPanel.wrap(Document.get().getElementById("login-input"), true); 
    form.setAction("javascript:;"); 
    form.addFormPanel(new FormPanel() {  // EDIT: method undefined?
             public void onSubmit(FormSubmitEvent event) {  
                // do some validation before submitting (non-empty fields) 
                // and call event.setCancelled(true) if needed. 

                // get the fields values and do your GWT-RPC call or 
                // RequestBuilder thing here. 
              } 
              public void onSubmitComplete(FormSubmitCompleteEvent event) { 
                 // will never be called. 
              } 
           });
```

However, form.addFormPanel method is undefined.

Comment: One reason for this is that my application userLogin service returns a "User" object by which is used by the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with GWT-RPC too (but you still need the `FormPanel` for similar `<form>`): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/KyzgtqqoJGE/5bqvG8pBSRYJ

Comment: Thanks. However the method addFormPanel described in the link is undefined. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

According to GWT FormPanel Javadoc :
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html

replace **form.addFormPanel** with :

- the deprecated method [form.addFormHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html#addFormHandler%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormHandler%29)
- which is now replaced with
  **form.addSubmitCompleteHandler** and **form.addSubmitHandler**